# Display all the fields associated with the record using Impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

Suppose, I have a **student table** with some fields in **impala**. Imagine there is a field called ***total_mark*** and I should find the student details with maximum mark from each branch.

My table is like this :-

[image: Student table]

In this table I have to get the ***details of student with maximum marks from each department***.
My query will be like this :-

```
select id,max(total_marks) from student_details group by department;
```

But using this query I can get only the id and total_marks. Provided there can be students with same name,age I can't group with fields like age,name .

So how should I query the table to get all the details of top student from each department ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of the JOIN concept

```
select stu.* 
from student_details stu 
join 
(  select department,max(total_marks) as max 
   from student_details 
   group by department
) rank 
on stu.department=rank.department and stu.total_marks=rank.max;
```